# Partial Fraction problem solution deviates from the Rule

Tags: calculus, integration, algebra-precalculus, partial-fractions

**Question:**

Compute $\displaystyle \int\frac{x^2+1}{(x^2+2)(x+1)} \, dx$

**My Approach:**

*As per my knowledge this integral can be divided in partial Fraction of form $\dfrac{Ax+B}{x^2+px+q}$ and then do the following as per to integrate it.*

**Solution:**

Taking $\dfrac{x^2+1}{(x^2+2)(x+1)}=\dfrac{Ax^2+Bx+C}{x^2+2}+\dfrac{D}{x+1}$

**Rule given:** Denominator g(x) contains quadratic tractor (may not be factorisable).
To each non-repeated quadratic factor of the form $x^2+px+q$(or $x^2+q$, $q$ not equal to $0$), there
Should be a partial Fraction of the form $Ax+B/(x^2+px+q)$.

**My problem:**

I can't understand why the solution provided deviates from the rule that I have studied to solve these kind of problems.

**Book:**

ISC MATHEMATICS XII

**Publishers:**

Kalyani

Comment: You should see [this](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to improve your mathematics formatting.

Comment: Where can I learn about the formatting?And can you edit it for me now?

Comment: Follow the hyperlink on "this" in my previous comment.

Comment: You haven't told us the rule you have studied, so we can't really explain why.

Comment: Thanks for notifying.

Comment: I have described the rule.Do it in your process and post the solution if you are having problem in understanding my provided rule that I have studied.

Comment: I assumed the "Solution" was your solution, since it came after "My Approach." If "Solution" is "Solution Provided," then make that clear. (The answerer below gets confused on this issue, as well.)

Comment: Sorry it's my mistake I should have been careful.

Comment: It's also possible there is a typo in the **statement** of the problem, and $\displaystyle \int\frac{x^2+1}{(x^3+2)(x+1)}dx$ was intended.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dividing $x^2+1$ by $x^2+2$ yields $1$ as the quotient and $-1$ as the remainder, so we have
$$
\frac{x^2+1}{x^2+2} = 1 - \frac 1 {x^2+2}.
$$
So
\begin{align}
& \frac{x^2+1}{(x^2+2)(x+1)} = \frac 1 {x+1} - \frac 1 {(x^2+2)(x+1)} \\[15pt]
= {} & \frac 1 {x+1} + \frac{Ax+B}{x^2+2} + \frac{\text{some constant}}{x+1} \\[15pt]
= {} & \frac{Ax+B}{x^2+2} + \frac C {x+1}
\end{align}
Thus I would decompose this into partial fractions in a way consistent with your approach.

Comment: Your explanation is the best.

Comment: @CalculusProgrammer : I'm glad it helped.

Answer (score 1):

you must write $$\frac{x^2+1}{(x^2+2)(x+1)}=\frac{Ax+B}{x^2+2}+\frac{C}{x+1}$$

Comment: Yes absolutely correct.Then is the solution given wrong ?

Comment: your solution is wrong, use my ansatz

Comment: Okay.Thanks for rectifying it.

Comment: no Problem, it's nice that i could help you

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, the solution in your book points that the fraction can be writeen as

$$ \frac{x^{2}+1}{(x^{2}+2)(x+1)} = \frac{Ax^{2}+Bx+C}{x^{2}+2}  + \frac{D}{x+1} $$
$$  = \frac{(Ax^{2}+Bx+C)(x+1) + D(x^{2}+2)}{(x^{2}+2)(x+1)} $$

Of course it can, you just need to find the *appropriate constants* :

$$ Ax^{3} + (A+B+ D)x^{2} + (B+C)x + (C+2D)  = x^{2}+1  $$
$$ \implies A = 0, \:\: A+B+D = 1, \:\: B+C = 0, \:\: C+2D=1$$
Now, actually, from this step, we can already see that $A=0$is a necessity, so the partial fractions must be of the form
$$\frac{Bx+C}{x^{2}+2}  + \frac{D}{x+1} $$
which is the rule that you already know.

Both the solution and the rule are correct, its just that using the rule will be more efficient.